# HIbernate : Primary key concept in Hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3 .
Hi ,

I am attending a session on Hibernate . I was confused about one of the discussion he had when working with Hibernate and Primary key in Tables under Database .

**What he mentioned is that ,When working with Hibernate , its not compulsary for a Database column to have a primary key , but its mandatory to mention a Primary Key hbm file representing that Table .**

Please let me know if this is true ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate needs a unique, immutable ID for each entity. Whereas this ID is declared as primary key or not in the database table mapped by this entity doesn't matter. But I don't see what you would gain by not declaring it as a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the response , i am working on a legacy Database , which is of 20 years old so not interested to change the structure of Databse , so i want to manage by simply adding a Primary key in hbm file and dont want to modify the Databse structure .

Comment: That's fine, if and only if the field you choose as ID uniquely identifies the record in the table, and if the value in this column never changes.